# I can't start libcamera on Raspberry pi. Error undefined symbol

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, undefined-symbol

I have little knowledge of **Linux** and have installed **libcamera** to stream video from rbpicamera to **vlc** (or **kodi**, **tvheadend**, etc). But it gives error and I don't know what is happening.

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 --width 1920 --height 1080 --codec h264 --inline --listen -o tcp://0.0.0.0:8888


[0:13:03.287872564] [2248]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3829-dfc6d711
[0:13:03.852263918] [2263]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1258 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:13:03.862314595] [2263]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1374 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media2 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:13:03.868779438] [2248]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 1280x960-YUV420
[0:13:03.872784647] [2263]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 1640x1232-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1640x1232-pBAA
libcamera-vid: symbol lookup error: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcamera_app.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK9libcamera11ControlList8containsERKNS_9ControlIdE
```

Let's see if you can give me a hand please.

It always gives the same error. I've reinstalled everything and it's still exactly the same. I've been around the net a thousand times and I haven't found the error or the solution.

Error:

```
libcamera-vid: symbol lookup error: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcamera_app.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK9libcamera11ControlList8containsERKNS_9ControlIdE
```

I'm with the S.O. **Dietpi** on a **Raspberry Pì 2**. The camera works perfectly.

Here is the guide I have followed to install **libcamera**:

https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html#

Comment: How did you install libcamera? And have you tried reproducing the problem using [raspbian os](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/)?

Comment: No way. I would have to install it on another sd. I will try it as soon as I can to see if I have the same error. Thanks.